# area=pi*r^2 : what loss/optimizer function to use, and why does the below loss function does not predict?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

By giving radius r and area of circle, I want the NN to predict correct values. However the below code did not predict. What change I need to make in loss/optimize function? Would be great if you provide some reasoning for choosing loss/optimize function.

```
from tensorflow import keras
import numpy as np
model = keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(units=1, input_shape=[1])])
model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='mean_squared_error')
radiusTrainValues = np.array([1.0,2.0,3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], dtype=float)
areaTrainValues = np.array([3.14159,12.56637, 28.27433,50.26548,78.53982,113.09734], dtype=float)


model.fit(radiusTrainValues, areaTrainValues, epochs=5000)


radiusTestVlues = np.array([7.0,8.0,9.0, 10.0], dtype=float)
areaTestVlues = np.array([153.93804,201.06193,254.469,314.15927], dtype=float)

print("Input    :",radiusTestVlues)
print("CorrectVlues   :",areaTestVlues)
print("TF Predicted:",model.predict(radiusTestVlues))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually The problem that you have, I believe, does not come from your loss function. Because your loss function is just an indicator of your prediction performance the optimizer will just adjust model parameter in the direction of gradient of your loss respect to each parameter (dLoss/dW). What happen here is you want to use a NN to approximate a function that calculate area f(r) = Pi * r^2 using only 1 neuron which is just f(r) = (W * r) + B. In simple word, you are trying to approximate a parabola function (r^2) using a linear function (W * r + B), therefore your loss will decrease until some point and stuck because that is the best it can do, you can try drawing that yourself and you will see there will be a huge gap between your line and parabola.

What you can do is increase number of layer and neuron you will see a huge improvement.